# How to configure Dreamweaver CS5 to run within a single application window

Tags: macos, layout, workspace, dreamweaver, adobe-cs5

I hope an experienced Dreamweaver CS5 user can save me a little time.  I'm running DW CS5 on OSX, and it has a toolbar that run across the top of the desktop.  There is a combo box on the toolbar that lets me change the workspace layout so that the editor and tool panels are aligned in a variety of positions and sizes, optimized for designers or developers.  For the most part, I like this feature, but there are times like now that I'd really like for everything to be contained within a single application window.  How can I configure DW so there is not toolbar stuck across the top and so the editor window and all tool panels are within a single application window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dreamweaver CS5/Mac is pretty darn flexible; it's really a question of what it is exactly that you're trying to do.

The Application Bar can be turned off (and on again) by choosing Window > Application Bar.

If you have multiple documents you want to combine into a single tabbed window, choose Window > Combine as Tabs.

The panels are a little trickier, though. Here are some options, one of which may work for you:

- You can turn them off (and on again) by clicking F4 or choosing Window > Hide Panels.
- You can turn them into buttons by clicking the Collapse to Icons button in the upper right corner of the panel dock.
- You can undock them by dragging the dock header bar out of the dock area. Once undocked, they can be moved, resized, and/or closed.
- And so on…

Comment: That is exactly the information I was hoping to learn.  

Adobe apparently is using unique methods of drawing or managing the windows because MercuryMover is only able to position the remaining, single, editor window and cannot resize it.  Anyhow, things are a little easier to manage now.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Especially not on OS X. OS X apps have always been very into the MDI style of interface you're trying to turn off.

Comment: Darn.  I use MercuryMover to snap a dozen applications into positions and sizes that are good for my workflow and DW is the only one is unmanageable because of its MDI style interface.  I can see the advantage that the interface offers if DW was the only app a person was running, but sometimes I just need a light-weight clean, easy to move around and resize window.